# library of books , struct and malloc

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free, stdio

I'm trying to do a  library
the books is the objectives
the user can enter a book and then I check if the book is my book menu:
**if the book in the menu:**

if the book is available so I print a message and return 1
if it doesn't available so I change the book to available and print that I added the book

**if  the book is not in the menu :**
I do malloc and then check I the malloc succeed
if the malloc succeed :I do strcp to the object
if the malloc didn't succeed : I do free to the object and the print a message and return 1

**The problem**: when the user enter the book for the second time it shouldn't add the book as a new book! it should check if the book is available or not and then return a message but my code is not doing this and I don't know where is bug!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define BOOK_NUM  4
#define NAME_LENGTH 200
#define AVAILABLE 10
#define NOT_AVAILABLE 20

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct book
{
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];  char author[NAME_LENGTH];  int available;  int times_borrowed;
}Book;

int main()
{
    Book *books[BOOK_NUM] = { 0 };
    char book_name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char author_name[NAME_LENGTH];
    int opreation = 0;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int m = 0;
    char tav;
    scanf("%d", &opreation);
    if (opreation == 1) {
        printf("please enter the name:");
        scanf("%c", &tav);
        do {// kelet of the book_name
            scanf("%c", &tav);
            if (tav == '\n')
                break;
            book_name[m] = tav;
            m++;
        } while (m < NAME_LENGTH);
        book_name[m] = '\0';
        for (i = 0; i < BOOK_NUM && *(books+i)!=NULL ; i++) {
            if (strcmp(*books[i]->name, book_name) == 0) 
            {
                if (books[i]->available = NOT_AVAILABLE)
                {
                    books[i]->available = AVAILABLE;
                    printf("This book is already in the library");
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("There is no enough space in the library");
                    return 0;
                } 
            
            }
        }  
             //befot bs eza 3ml sreka ghad 3la kolshe w ma tghyr eshe 
        for (j; j < BOOK_NUM; j++) {
            if (books[j] == NULL)
            {
                books[j] = (Book*)malloc(sizeof(Book));
            if (books[j] != NULL)
            {
                strcpy(books[j]->name, book_name);
                printf("Please enter author name:");
                m = 0;
                do {// kelet of the book_name
                    scanf("%c", &tav);
                    if (tav == '\n')
                        break;
                    author_name[m] = tav;
                    m++;
                } while (m < NAME_LENGTH);
                author_name[m] = '\0';
                strcpy(books[j]->author, author_name);
                books[j]->available = AVAILABLE;
                books[j]->times_borrowed = 0;
                printf("The book %s was successfully added!", book_name);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                    for (int k = 0; k < BOOK_NUM && books[k]!=NULL; k++) {
                        free(books[k]);
                    }
                    printf("NO MEMORY");
                    return 1;
             }
                
            }
        }
    } 

 }
```

Comment: This seems like a very good time to learn two things: First of all to not write large parts of code without testing (divide and conquer is very useful in software development); And how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: You only do one command per program invocation. You do not read from a file nor write to a file. That is, you don't store any data you create in a file so that it can persist across program invocations. Is the assignment to use a file? Or, are you just supposed to loop on commands (i.e. the program will execute as many commands as you want)?

Comment: Note that `if (strcmp(*books[i]->name, book_name) == 0)` generated a compiler warning. I suggest `if (strcmp(books[i]->name, book_name) == 0)`

Comment: @CraigEstey i cant use file in this assignment ....maybe fgets function can help??

Answer (score 0):

MAYBE now is better:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define BOOK_NUM  4
#define NAME_LENGTH 200
#define AVAILABLE 10
#define NOT_AVAILABLE 20

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct book
{
    char name[NAME_LENGTH];  char author[NAME_LENGTH];  int available;  int times_borrowed;
}Book;

int main()
{
    Book *books[BOOK_NUM] = { 0 };
    char book_name[NAME_LENGTH];
    char author_name[NAME_LENGTH];
    int opreation = 0;
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    int m = 0;
    char tav;
    scanf("%d", &opreation);
    if (opreation == 1) {
        printf("please enter the name:");
        scanf("%c", &tav);
        do {// kelet of the book_name
            scanf("%c", &tav);
            if (tav == '\n')
                break;
            book_name[m] = tav;
            m++;
        } while (m < NAME_LENGTH);
        book_name[m] = '\0';
        for (i = 0; i < BOOK_NUM && *(books+i)!=NULL ; i++) {
            if (strcmp(books[i]->name, book_name) == 0)
            {
                if (books[i]->available == NOT_AVAILABLE)
                {
                    books[i]->available = AVAILABLE;
                    printf("This book is already in the library");
                    return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("There is no enough space in the library");
                    return 0;
                }

            }
        }
             //befot bs eza 3ml sreka ghad 3la kolshe w ma tghyr eshe

      if (books[j] == NULL)
      {
          books[j] = (Book*)malloc(sizeof(Book));
      if (books[j] != NULL)
      {
          strcpy(books[j]->name, book_name);
          printf("Please enter author name:");
          m = 0;
          do {// kelet of the book_name
              scanf("%c", &tav);
              if (tav == '\n')
                  break;
              author_name[m] = tav;
              m++;
          } while (m < NAME_LENGTH);
          author_name[m] = '\0';
          strcpy(books[j]->author, author_name);
          books[j]->available = AVAILABLE;
          books[j]->times_borrowed = 0;
          printf("The book %s was successfully added!", book_name);
          return 0;
      }
      else
      {
              for (int k = 0; k < BOOK_NUM && books[k]!=NULL; k++) {
                  free(books[k]);
              }
              printf("NO MEMORY");
              return 1;
       }

      }

    }

 }
```

by the way, you should listen to compiler warnings.